# Audio descriptor MFCC in C#

Tags: c#, audio, signals, speech-recognition, mfcc

I'm doing primitive speech recognition and need simple descriptor for my audio signals.
Now I have only FFT from my audio signal, but I don't know what should I do after that. When I tried use Hidden Markov Models with only FFT from my training signals, it gives me wrong answers.

Could you tell me about any C# libraries, which help me change my FFT signal to MFCC(Mel Frequency Cepstrum Coefficients)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know such libraries for C# but I can show you my implementation of extracting 20 MFCC from massive of amplitudes of wav-file with 16 kHz sample frequency.

You have to use `MatNet.Numerics` and `MathNet.Filtering` [libraries](http://www.mathdotnet.com/).

Only Russian comments, sorry.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.IntegralTransforms;
using MathNet.Numerics.Signals;
using MathNet.Filtering;

namespace MFCC
{
class MFCC_calculating
{
    public double[] frame;        //один фрейм
    public double[,] frame_mass;  //массив всех фреймов по 2048 отсчетов или 128 мс        
    public Complex[,] frame_mass_FFT;     //массив результатов FFT для всех фреймов


    int[] filter_points = {6,18,31,46,63,82,103,127,154,184,218,
                              257,299,348,402,463,531,608,695,792,901,1023};//массив опорных точек для фильтрации спекрта фрейма
    double[,] H = new double[20, 1024];     //массив из 20-ти фильтров для каждого MFCC

    double[] MFCC = new double[20];     //массив MFCC для данной речевой выборки   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    /// <summary>
    /// Функция для расчета MFCC для сигнала с частотой дискретизации 16кГц
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wav_PCM">Массив значений амплитуд аудиосигнала</param>
    /// <returns>Массив из 20-ти MFCC</returns>
    public double[] MFCC_20_calculation(double[] wav_PCM)
    {
        int count_frames = (wav_PCM.Length * 2 / 2048) + 1; //количество отрезков в сигнале

        RMS_gate(wav_PCM);          //применение noise gate
        Normalize(wav_PCM);         //нормализация
        frame_mass = Set_Frames(wav_PCM);       //формирование массива фреймов
        Hamming_window(frame_mass, count_frames);        //окно Хэмминга для каждого отрезка
        frame_mass_FFT = FFT_frames(frame_mass, count_frames);       //FFT для каждого фрейма


        double[,] MFCC_mass = new double[count_frames, 20];         //массив наборов MFCC для каждого фрейма

        //***********   Расчет гребенчатых фильтров спектра:    *************
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
            {
                if (j < filter_points[i]) H[i, j] = 0;
                if ((filter_points[i] <= j) & (j <= filter_points[i + 1]))
                    H[i, j] = ((double)(j - filter_points[i]) / (filter_points[i + 1] - filter_points[i]));
                if ((filter_points[i + 1] <= j) & (j <= filter_points[i + 2]))
                    H[i, j] = ((double)(filter_points[i + 2] - j) / (filter_points[i + 2] - filter_points[i + 1]));
                if (j > filter_points[i + 2]) H[i, j] = 0;
            }

        for (int k = 0; k < count_frames; k++)
        {
            //**********    Применение фильтров и логарифмирование энергии спектра для каждого фрейма   ***********
            double[] S = new double[20];
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1024; j++)
                {
                    S[i] += Math.Pow(frame_mass_FFT[k, j].Magnitude, 2) * H[i, j];
                }
                if (S[i] != 0) S[i] = Math.Log(S[i], Math.E);
            }

            //**********    DCT и массив MFCC для каждого фрейма на выходе     ***********
            for (int l = 0; l < 20; l++)
                for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) MFCC_mass[k, l] += S[i] * Math.Cos(Math.PI * l * ((i * 0.5) / 20));
        }

        //***********   Рассчет конечных MFCC для всей речевой выборки    ***********       
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < count_frames; k++) MFCC[i] += MFCC_mass[k, i];
            MFCC[i] = MFCC[i] / count_frames;
        }

        return MFCC;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Функция для подавления шума по среднекравратичному уровню
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wav_PCM">Массив значений амплитуд аудиосигнала</param>
    private void RMS_gate(double[] wav_PCM)
    {
        int k = 0;
        double[] buf_rms = new double[50];
        double RMS = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < wav_PCM.Length; j++)
        {
            if (k < 100)
            {
                RMS += Math.Pow((wav_PCM[j]), 2);
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Math.Sqrt(RMS / 100) < 0.005)
                    for (int i = j - 100; i <= j; i++) wav_PCM[i] = 0;
                k = 0; RMS = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Функция нормализации сигнала
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wav_PCM">Массив значений амплитуд аудиосигнала</param>
    private void Normalize(double[] wav_PCM)
    {
        double[] abs_wav_buf = new double[wav_PCM.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < wav_PCM.Length; i++)
            if (wav_PCM[i] < 0) abs_wav_buf[i] = -wav_PCM[i];   //приводим все значения амплитуд к абсолютной величине 
            else abs_wav_buf[i] = wav_PCM[i];                    //для определения максимального пика
        double max = abs_wav_buf.Max();
        double k = 1f / max;        //получаем коэффициент нормализации            

        for (int i = 0; i < wav_PCM.Length; i++)    //записываем нормализованные значения в исходный массив амплитуд
        {
            wav_PCM[i] = wav_PCM[i] * k;              
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Функция для формирования двумерного массива отрезков сигнала длиной по 128мс.
    /// При этом начало каждого следующего отрезка делит предыдущий пополам
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wav_PCM">Массив значений амплитуд аудиосигнала</param>
    private double[,] Set_Frames(double[] wav_PCM)
    {
        double[,] frame_mass_1;  //массив всех фреймов по 2048 отсчетов или 128 мс
        int count_frames = 0;       
        int count_samp = 0;

        frame_mass_1 = new double[(wav_PCM.Length*2 / 2048) + 1, 2048];
        for (int j = 0; j < wav_PCM.Length; j++)
        {
            if (j >= 1024)      //запись фреймов в массив
            {
                count_samp++;
                if (count_samp >= 2049)
                {
                    count_frames += 2;
                    count_samp = 1;
                }
                frame_mass_1[count_frames, count_samp - 1] = wav_PCM[j - 1024];
                frame_mass_1[count_frames + 1, count_samp - 1] = wav_PCM[j];
            }
        }
        return frame_mass_1;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Оконная функция Хэмминга
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frames">Двумерный массив отрезвов аудиосигнала</param>
    /// <param name="wav_PCM">Массив значений амплитуд аудиосигнала</param>
    private void Hamming_window(double[,] frames, int count_frames)
    {
        double omega = 2.0 * Math.PI / (2048f);
        for (int i = 0; i < count_frames; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2048; j++)
                frames[i, j] = (0.54 - 0.46 * Math.Cos(omega * (j))) * frames[i, j];
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Быстрое преобразование фурье для набора отрезков
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frames">Двумерный массив отрезвов аудиосигнала</param>
    /// <param name="wav_PCM">Массив значений амплитуд аудиосигнала</param>
    private Complex[,] FFT_frames(double[,] frames, int count_frames)
    {
        Complex[,] frame_mass_complex =
            new Complex[count_frames, 2048]; //для хранения результатов FFT каждого фрейма в комплексном виде
        Complex[] FFT_frame = new Complex[2048];     //спектр одного фрейма
        for (int k = 0; k < count_frames; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) FFT_frame[i] = frames[k, i];
            Transform.FourierForward(FFT_frame, FourierOptions.Matlab);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) frame_mass_complex[k, i] = FFT_frame[i];
        }
        return frame_mass_complex;
    }
}
}
```